# ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) when uploading video using retrofit 2

Tags: java, file-upload, retrofit2

I am using this code to upload my videos to the retrofit server

```
private String uploadVideoToServer(String pathToVideoFile) {
    Log.v("test_get", "get the file");
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    SmileVideoAPI service = retrofit.create(SmileVideoAPI.class);
    MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
    File videoFile = new File(pathToVideoFile);
    //RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, videoFile);
    ProgressRequestBody videoBody = new ProgressRequestBody(videoFile, this);
    MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", videoFile.getName(), videoBody);
    RequestBody description = createPartFromString("desc");
    Log.v("test_get", "before uploading");
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadVideo(description, vFile);
    Log.v("test_get", "after uploading");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("mok", "S");
                ResponseBody rb = response.body();
                Log.i("mok", rb.toString());
                mProgress.setProgress(100);
                Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, UploadCompleteActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Log.i("mok", "F");
                ResponseBody rb = response.errorBody();
                Log.i("mok", rb.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("mok", t.getCause() + "");
            Log.i("mok", "T");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    return msg;
}
```

It uploaded the video for first times the connection is set, however, it throws out the following error below from time to time.

libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Can anyone explain me why is this happening, and how can I fix it? Right now, I am looking into solutions how I can close my connection since I doubt that it might be because of the unclosed connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is causing because the connection is not released, 
I solved this by putting a

```
response.body().close();
```